# ImageLayer with ImageWMS rendering (ol update from 6.2.1 to 6.13.0)

Tags: openlayers, wms

After updating OpenLayers I'm noticing a rendering change on an ImageLayer

```
let newWMSLayer = new ImageLayer({
                visible: true,
                source: new ImageWMS({
                    url: 'the URL',
                    imageLoadFunction: (image, src) => {

                        let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'image/png8' });
                        this.httpClient.get(src, {
                            headers: headers,
                            withCredentials: true,
                            responseType: 'blob'
                        }).subscribe((res: any) => {
                            let object = URL.createObjectURL(res);
                            let imageElement = image.getImage() as any;
                            imageElement.src = object;
                        });

                    },
                    params: {
                        LAYERS: layer.Name,
                        TILED: false,
                        VERSION: '1.3.0',
                        FORMAT: 'image/png8'
                    },
                    serverType: 'geoserver',
                    ratio: 1
                })
            });
```

With **6.2.1**  on a zoom or pan event the new image is somehow rendered on top of the old one.
With **6.13.0** on a zoom or pan event the old image is removed from canvas and after some miliseconds the new image is rendered resulting in a **flicker effect**.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This reads more like a bug report than a Question, and prompting for "thoughts" makes this more *discussion-oriented* / *opinion-based* than the Focused question/Best answer model can support.

Comment: It was a bug introduced in 6.13 and fixed in 6..14  See #13463 in the release notes https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases/tag/v6.14.0

Comment: @Mike Yeap that was it exactly thanks. Would you like to add an answer so that other can maybe find it useful?